# How to request access token from Salesforce using code authorization flow via axios

Tags: axios, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I have a connected app in salesforce with a secret and id. I'm able to generate a code and have it sent to my sever. I then want to exchange the code for an access token. To do that I need to create a POST request to salesforce. The documentation for that can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5).

However, I keep getting a 400 error. Here is my axios request:

```
  const data = {
    code,
    grant_type,
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    redirect_uri,
    code_verifier,
    code_challenge
  };

  const response = await axios.post('https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
    null,
    {
      params: data,
      headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    }
  );
```

I've also tried:

```
  const response = await axios.post('https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
    querystring.stringify(data),
    {
      headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    }
  );
```

both times I'm getting a 400. How am I supposed to format the request?